# Android Google Map min zoom

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have implemented a Google Map Api v2 in my Android App with zoom control.

```
map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```

I'd like to zoom out to view the entire world but it seems the min zoom level is set to 2 or higher.
Is there any way to achieve this behavior ?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Even the GoogleMaps App (on Android) does not allow to zoom to a view of the entire world. So I think there is no way.

Comment: I never thought about it until now...THANKS for your comment

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can work around this by listening to camera change and reset zoom when needed.

```
    map.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
      float maxZoom = 17.0f;
      float minZoom = 2.0f;

      if (position.zoom > maxZoom) {
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(maxZoom));
      } else if (position.zoom < minZoom) {
      map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(minZoom));
     }
   }
```